# Custom template file for displaying the inner blog contents

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I am trying to create a custom layout for my blog listing and blog content display pages.

The following url will display all the latest blogs based on the conditions that I have set.

`http://fqdn/general-blog`

When I click on the 'Read more' button corresponding to a button, it will display the full blog contents in another page.

Sample format : `http://fqdn/general-blog/tourist-details`

I am able to modify the layout of the page corresponding to blog listing. For this, I have created a custom tpl file : page--general-blog.tpl.php.

What I want is to create a new template file for displaying the contents of individual blogs.

The individual blog content display page is not entering - page--general-blog.tpl.php file. It's always using the template - page.tpl.php.

I tried creating separate tpl files like :

`page--general-blog--%.tpl.php`

But, the changes in this template is not getting effect in the individual blog content display page.

How should I move forward. Has someone had any similar situations?

Comment: Are you using CCK+Views or a custom module for this listing and content type?

Answer (score 0):

If your content type has name `general-blog`,you should name single blog entry template as `node--general-blog.tpl.php`. See
[Theming nodes by content type](https://www.drupal.org/node/17565) for details.

If you need to theme whole page template depending on node type, you should add following code in your template.php:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['node']) && !empty($variables['node']->type)) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__' . $variables['node']->type;
  }
}
```

And then use `page--node--general-blog.tpl.php` file (see [Page templates depending on node type](https://www.drupal.org/node/249726) for details).

Don't forget to [clear the theme registry](https://www.drupal.org/node/173880#theme-registry) after creating new template file.